# Remove Log4j and use Logback

Tags: log4j, corda

Is it possible to use Logback instead of Log4j? I have excluded the log4j dependencies from all my projects grade files but when I build the nodes log4j still gets brought in from Corda-core.

Below is how I excluded the dependencies in gradle.

```
configurations.all {
  exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-api'
  exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-core'
  exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-slf4j-impl'
  exclude group: "org.slf4j", module: "jcl-over-slf4j"
  exclude group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', module: 'log4j-web'
}
```

I then added logback as a dependency

```
compile group: 'ch.qos.logback', name: 'logback-classic', version: '1.2.3'
```

But after deploying the nodes and starting them up I can see that they still use the log4j logger factory.

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/daniel.newton/.capsule/apps/net.corda.node.Corda_3.1-corda/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.9.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/daniel.newton/dev/projects/corda/build/nodes/party/cordapps/trade-input-cordapp-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/daniel.newton/dev/projects/corda/build/nodes/party/cordapps/common-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/Users/daniel.newton/dev/projects/corda/build/nodes/party/cordapps/corda-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

These log lines suggest that logback has not even been found.

One extra piece of information is that, when I run the tests that exist within in one of the same projects as the cordapps below runs fine and picks up logback successfully but running the nodes does not.

Comment: Simply remove log4j and slf4j->log4j binding jars from the class path, and add Logback, and Logback->slf4j binding into class path. And don't forget to replace log4j with Logback configuration.

Comment: @VictorGubin I have run `gradle dependencies` and have no log4j dependencies anywhere to be found, but log4j is still being picked up each time (which I know means its still there somewhere). Somehow the `net.corda.node.Corda_3.1-corda/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.9.1.jar!` seems to include it still. I have also done a `clean build`.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice for the choice of logging framework is that it should be defined at the *application* level, not at the library (cordapp) level.

In the case of cordapps, one should use the `SLF4J` API, and leave it to the runtime (`corda.jar`) to decide the appropriate binding. `corda.jar` uses the log4j implementation. Perhaps you need to raise an issue on github for the ability to switch log providers.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency on log4j in Corda Core is removed by this PR, which will be in the next major Corda release: https://github.com/corda/corda/pull/3257.

However, I would echo dazraf's views on best practice here.